# Android dim Dialog background doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, android, dialog, themes

I'm trying to create a simple Dialog with a custom progress bar.
But for some reason, I can only get the background fully translucent (by adding Theme_Translucent_NoTitle) or fully darkned (by removing Translucent from theme).

What I want to do though, is to be able to play with the dim amount. Here's the code:

```
public class ProgressWheelDialog extends Dialog{

private ProgressWheel pw;

public ProgressWheelDialog(final Context ctx) {
    // to make transparent  background, add Translucent after Theme_
    super(ctx, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progresswheel);

    // dim background
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.dimAmount = .5f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

    // get and spin progress wheel
    pw = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
    pw.setVisibility(ProgressWheel.VISIBLE);
    pw.spin();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Code above darkens the screen completely (except the progress bar of course)

Comment: Call " getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);" after "getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);"

Comment: @kozaxinan it is still not working

Answer (score 5):

You need to set dim after you show dialog.

```
    dialog.show();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.dimAmount=0.5f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: How do I play with the values? Tried changing 7 to other numbers but it looks the same

Comment: Just fine tuning the darkness values until I'm satisfied. With dim amount I could play between 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: In a matter of fact, it doesn't even work. No matter what value I put inside, background seems quite translucent.

Comment: Here's an instance: http://bit.ly/1yygfac
Tried putting 0x19191919 for example, which according to here is the color I want, but no result: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp?colorhex=000000

Comment: Did you delete your dim code and write my answer in where you call this dialog? I try it with alertdialog and successfully dim the background. @Jjang

Comment: Ok so it dims my screen (I didnt notice it because the dim was in specific color, and now when I changed background I see it). How can I play with the values? basically I want black color, and make it alittle transparent.

Comment: You can play dim amount. lp.dimAmount=1f; make it black.

Comment: meant your previously answer with colordrawable...just set it's color to black, and added alpha value to make it transparent.